# Updating a QListView when objects change externally

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I've a simple question regarding the update of a **QTreeView** (or any subclass of **QAbstractItemView**) when a model object changes externally. Let's say that a list shows a subclass of **QAbstractItemModel**, and an item of that model gets changed outside of the list window, and we would like to update the list with the change. What is the usual strategy to achieve something like this ? I've looked at the Qt documentation of **QAbstractItemModel** and there is a signal named '***dataChanged***' that is (or should be) emited when data from the model changes. But since this signal (as all QAbstractItemModel functions/signals/slots) work with a **QModelIndex**, which is not persistent as the documentation clearly says, am i supposed to store somehow a mapping of my data to **QPersistentModelIndex**(es), so when my data change i will be able to find the corresponding **QPersistenModelIndex** and use that as argument to the various **QAbstractItemModel** functions ? Is that what **QPersistentModelIndex**(es) are used for ? Or am i missing something ?

Thank you.

ps: I guess i could just reload the **QTreeView**, but then i wouldn't know which items were expanded or which were selected. Is there an strategy to overcome this problem and just reload the list ?

Answer (score 8):

`QTreeView` already handles the case in which the underlying model's data changed (i.e. the model has emitted the `dataChanged()` signal). That means you don't need to do any additional work on the view.

If you're implementing your own model (a derived class of `QAbstractItemView`), and you're making a change to the contents of the model, you simply need to emit the `dataChanged()` signal when your change is complete. The signal/slot mechanism will automatically inform the view using that signal.

Comment: "If you're implementing your own model (a derived class of QAbstractItemView)," I think you meant a derived class of QAbstractItemModel.